# How to use Nokia HERE API in R

Tags: r, here-api, shapefile

I am trying to download the coordinates of a Reverse Flow Isoline (https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-routing/topics/resource-reverse-flow.html) from the Nokia HERE Enterprise API.

I am able to run the query, and get a long list of latitude+longitude, but when I try to create and plot a SpatialPolygon, I see that the order of the points seem random. the graph looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVxql.png

```
my.coord.pairs <- points.from.nokia.here.api

  pol <- spChFIDs(block[1,], paste("newid", 3324234, sep = ""))

  pol@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords <- matrix(my.coord.pairs, nrow = length(my.coord.pairs)/2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

  ggplot(pol, aes(long, lat, group = group)) + 
        theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + 
         geom_polygon(colour = "black", size = 1) + coord_equal() + 
        labs(x = "Easting", y = "Northing", fill = "Population") + 
         scale_fill_manual("Test", values = c(alpha("Red", 0.4), "white"), labels = c("a", "b"))
```

P.S.: "block" is a Polygon that I got from a U.S. Census shapefile.

P.S.2: I know here exists the geocodeHERE R package, but it is still very premature and does not offer isolines and reverse flow calculations.

Comment: not a reproducible example, at least include dummy data to allow us to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Scott Chamberlain, I agree with you that my question was not well assembled.

The answer is that my understanding of the Reverse Flow resource was wrong. It does *not* return a polygon like the Calculate Isoline resource. Moreover, it is today a legacy resource of the API.

The correct way to retrieve what I wanted -- the polygon representing all places *from* where you can start driving and do reach a given destination point within a given limit either of travel time or of travel distance -- is to use the Calculate Isoline resource with a **destination** argument instead of a **start** argument.

This double functionality (destination/start) of the Calculate Isoline resource goes a bit unnoticed in the API documentation, nevertheless it works as it should: https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-isoline.html#resource-calculate-isoline

Below follows my piece of code that makes a request to the Calculate Isoline resource and then unpacks the returned data to get the polygon (i.e. the list of points that form the polygon). Please notice that the code requires an APP ID and APP Code, which you get when you create a HERE API account.

```
# These variables below are just to compose the example code.
latitude <- 34.9859619
longitude <- -78.5900116
range <- 1800 # 30 minutes, in seconds
resolution <- 5

# Now comes the real code
response_parsed <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(RCurl::getURL(paste0("http://isoline.route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json",
"?app_id=", App_id, "&app_code=", App_code, "&range=", range, "&rangetype=time", "&destination=geo!", latitude, ",",
longitude, "&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled")))

if(length(response_parsed) == 0)
  stop('Error in JSON request.')

polygon <- data.frame(long=numeric, lat=numeric)

# The points (latitude+longitude) come together as characters separated by a comma. We need to split them.
for(rsh in response_parsed$response$isoline[[1]]$component[[1]]$shape) {
  split <- strsplit(rsh, ",")[[1]]
  polygon <- rbind(polygon, data.frame(long=as.numeric(split[[2]]), lat=as.numeric(split[[1]])))
}
# Now the polygon data frame contains all points that form the polygon returned by Calculate Isoline.
```